# Batch queries in twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I need to run a query that returns a list of users, along with data about those users.  Suppose I consider one person and I want to know where all his/her followers are.  This query:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name={screen_name}
```

returns a list of user ids of the person's followers.  I can then plug each user id into this query:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id={user_id}
```

to get information about the user, including location.  But that means that if the person has 1000 followers, I would have to call the second query 1000 times.  It would be better to do a "join" (as it would be called in SQL), where we could ask for the followers AND their locations, and do this in one query, but I can't see how to do this.

Is this possible? Also, when asking for user lookup, is it possible to specify that you only want one field and not the whole user record (kind of like asking for `select single_field` instead of `select *` in SQL)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enumerate multiple `user_id`s in query. Example:
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=351927492,8602462,132533067,16984020,131217651,125764179

But you capped to 100 values (names, ids) per query, so for user with 1000 followers you have to make 10 queries.

**Update** For 1.1 version of API correct URL would be http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=351927492,8602462,132533067,16984020,131217651,125764179

Comment: Thanks.  It's not quite a join, but it does reduce the number of queries from 1001 to 11, so I guess that's good enough.  Do you know anything about the other question, limiting the results in the users lookup to just the fields of interest?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank As I know, such possibility is not build-in in twitter API, but since JSON manipulations are pretty easy in most languages, that wouldn't be a problem (except if you aware of amount of data downloaded).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You get the JSON as a result, but if they send much more data than you really need, it wastes bandwidth.  Agreed, getting the data you need from the result won't be hard, but it would be better not to ask for so much more than you need.

Comment: I meant you can't do it on twitter side. You can on yours.